# How do I run a REST Request test step twice, at the same time, using Groovy?

Tags: groovy, soapui

I'm trying to run both on separate threads, but according to the transaction log, both requests are being made sequentially, one after another, and not the same time:

[image]

Here is my Groovy code:

```
class SampleThread extends Thread {

    def testRunner

    SampleThread (testRunner) {
        this.testRunner = testRunner    
    }

    void run() {
        runTestStep()   
    }

    void runTestStep() {
        testRunner.runTestStepByName("POST accounts")
    }
}

def thread1 = new SampleThread(testRunner)
def thread2 = new SampleThread(testRunner)

thread1.start()
thread1.join()
thread2.start()
thread2.join()
```

Answer (score 0):

It may be a bit hard to visualize, but your code is exactly the same as a single thread doing the same work as the two threads you spin up and then join:

```
thread1.start() // this starts the other thread to do some work
// this is where your main thread would normally do other work
thread1.join() // here your main thread waits for thread1 to complete
thread2.start() // again you start a third thread
// again you do no work here
thread2.join() // but instead immediately wait for the thread to complete
```

This is akin to a relay race in which the first thread hands off to `thread1` for a while, waits for her to return with the "baton" of execution, receives the baton and immediately hands it to `thread2` and waits for her to return the "baton."

If you indeed need 3 threads to do the work of your program, you'd want something like this:

```
thread1.start()
thread2.start()

def sum = (0..1000).sumBy { it } // or some other work for your main thread to do

thread1.join()
thread2.join()
```

Hope this helps.